# How to test form submission

Tags: go, testing, go-gin

I have a login form with some html that users fill in:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form"><input name="username"> </div>
        <div class="form">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

I would like to test that the username is being received correctly. I am able to send a multipart form however this is contained within the **body** of the request not as a **postform**.

```golang
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Set("username", "Bob")

    // Create request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/login", strings.NewReader(form.Encode())) // sends as multipart form in request body
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/www-form-urlencoded")
    testRouter.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
```

How do I make a request with the form data attached as a Postform so that I can extract it `c.Postform("username")` from the backend as if submitted via the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns as you can simply do `req.PostForm = form`....

Answer (score 1):

keep button in the form with button type submit

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form">
      <input name="username"> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Apologies my bad I should have been clearer - I do have a submit button. I'll edit my question accordingly.